# Shiny if statement with prettyRadioButtons & checkboxGroupInput

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shinyapps, shiny-reactivity

My ShinyApp need two groups of checkboxes (`check1` and `check2` in my code below). The app will populate different dropdown menus based on user's selection.

However, `if else` statement seems work fine with `prettyRadioButtons`, but when I apply it to `checkboxGroupInput` it doesn't work. A simplified version of my app is shown below. Am I missing something in my `if` statement? Thanks in advance!

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Dynamic Boxes"),
  fluidRow(
    prettyRadioButtons("check1", "Please Pick", c("Option 1" = "op1", "Option 2" = "op2"), selected=character(0), shape="square", outline = T, inline = T),
    checkboxGroupInput("check2", "Please Pick", c("Option 3" = "op3", "Option 4" = "op4"), inline = T),

    fluidRow(hidden(selectInput('select_1', 'No.1 Select',choices = list1))),
    fluidRow(hidden(selectInput('select_2', 'No.2 Select',choices = list2))),
    fluidRow(hidden(selectInput('select_3', 'No.3 Select',choices = list3))),
    fluidRow(hidden(selectInput('select_4', 'No.4 Select',choices = list4))),
    fluidRow(hidden(selectInput('select_5', 'No.5 Select',choices = list5)))
  )
)


server <- function(input, output){
  observeEvent(input$check1, {
    if(!is.null(input$check1)){
      if(input$check1 == 'op1'){
        showElement('select_1')
      }
      else if(input$check1 == 'op2'){
        if(length(input$check2) == 1){
          if(input$check2 == 'op3'){showElement('select_2')}
          else if(input$check2 == 'op4'){showElement('select_3')}
        } 
        else if(length(input$check2) == 2){showElement('select_4')}
      }
    }
  })

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the simplified version of your App, could you make a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) out of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below implements your if-else logic for the `selectInput` using `renderUI`: 1) it displays nothing as long as none of the radio buttons is selected; 2) it shows options in `list1` if button 1 ("Option 1") is chosen; 3) if button 2 ("Option 2") is chosen it displays nothing as long as none of the checkboxes is ticked, shows options in `list2` if only checkbox 1 ("Option 3") is ticked, options in `list3` if only checkbox 2 ("Option 4") is ticked and options in `list4` if both checkboxes are ticked. In your example code options in `list5` will never be rendered, so hard for me to tell where you want to place it and I've ignored it.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

list1 = letters[1:3]
list2 = letters[4:6]
list3 = letters[7:9]
list4 = letters[10:12]

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Dynamic Boxes"),
  fluidRow(
    prettyRadioButtons("check1", "Please Pick", c("Option 1" = "op1", "Option 2" = "op2"), selected=character(0), shape="square", outline = T, inline = T),
    checkboxGroupInput("check2", "Please Pick", c("Option 3" = "op3", "Option 4" = "op4"), inline = T),
    uiOutput("select")
  )
)


server <- function(input, output){

  output$select = renderUI({

    req(input$check1) 

    if (input$check1 == 'op1') {
      selectInput('select_1', 'No.1 Select',choices = list1)
    } 
    else if (input$check1 == 'op2') {
      req(input$check2)
      if (length(input$check2) == 1) {
        if(input$check2 == 'op3') {
          selectInput('select_2', 'No.2 Select',choices = list2)
        }
        else if (input$check2 == 'op4') {
          selectInput('select_3', 'No.3 Select',choices = list3)
        }
      } 
      else if(length(input$check2) == 2){
        selectInput('select_4', 'No.4 Select',choices = list4)
      }
    }
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I think the combination of radio buttons and check boxes is perhaps a bit complicated, since based on the labels showing list 4, for example, is really a combination of options 2-4. You may have a good reason for that design choice in which case great! But if not, then perhaps a slightly modified design such as below would make things easier for the user (and yourself!).

```
# Continuing from above ----
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Dynamic Boxes"),
  fluidRow(
    prettyRadioButtons("check1", "Please Pick", c("Option 1" = "op1", "Option 2" = "op2"), selected=character(0), shape="square", outline = T, inline = T),
    uiOutput("check2"),
    uiOutput("select")
  )
)


server <- function(input, output) {

  output$check2 = renderUI({
    req(input$check1)
    if (input$check1=='op2') {
      prettyRadioButtons("check2", "Please Pick", 
                         c("Option 2.1" = "op3", "Option 2.2" = "op4", "Option 2.3" = "op5"), 
                         selected=character(0), shape="square", outline = T, inline = T)
    }
  })

  output$select = renderUI({
    req(input$check1) 
    if (input$check1 == 'op1') {
      selectInput('select_1', 'No.1 Select',choices = list1)
    } 
    else if (input$check1 == 'op2') {
      req(input$check2)
      if (input$check2 == 'op3') {
        selectInput('select_2', 'No.2 Select',choices = list2)
      } else if (input$check2== 'op4') {
        selectInput('select_3', 'No.3 Select',choices = list3)
      } else {
        selectInput('select_4', 'No.4 Select',choices = list4)
      }
    }
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Hope this helps!